NextJS React Query invalidateQueries not seems to be working
I'm using Nextjs with the app router but whenever i use any of my hooks that invalidate queries so i can see the data refreshed on my tables it seems to doesnt work, seeing on the Devtools the queries does never invalidates, this happens with all of my hooks, here is one of them:
"use client";

import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "@tanstack/react-query-devtools";
import { useState } from "react";

export const ReactQueryClientProvider = ({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) => {
  const [queryClient] = useState(
    () =>
      new QueryClient({
        defaultOptions: {
          queries: {
            staleTime: 60 * 1000,
          },
        },
      }),
  );
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      {children}
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={true} />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
};


Here is one of the hooks
const queryClient = new QueryClient();

export function useUpdateFlete(id: number) {
  
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: async (data: EditarFleteFormValues) =>
      fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/fletes/${id}`, {
        method: "PATCH",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }).then((res) => res.json() as Promise<Fletes>),
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["fletes", id] });
    },
  });
}

And then i use it on my component like this
const endFlete = useEndFlete(flete.id);

const handleEndFlete = async () => {
    try {
      await endFlete.mutateAsync();
      toast({
        variant: "default",
        title: "Exito",
        description: "Se ha finalizado el viaje.",
      });
      //router.refresh();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  };

Here is how the layour.tsx looks like:
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <ClerkProvider
      appearance={{
        baseTheme: dark,
      }}
    >
      <html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning>
        <body className={`${inter.className} overflow-hidden`}>
          <Providers>
            <Toaster />
            <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
              <ReactQueryClientProvider>{children}</ReactQueryClientProvider>
            </Suspense>
          </Providers>
        </body>
      </html>
    </ClerkProvider>
  );
}

I'm using the latest version of reactquery v5
I did already tried to play with the config flags for the queryClient and still not managed to make it work. The onSuccess is being triggered but do not invalidate the queries

That's because you are using a new QueryClient for the invalidation. The QueryClient holds the cache, so if you create a new one, it knows nothing about the one you passed to the QueryClientProvider.
Not sure where you have that syntax from - none of the examples or docs ever create a new QueryClient() for invalidation. Instead, you have to get the one from the context with useQueryClient:
export function useUpdateFlete(id: number) {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()
  
  return useMutation(...)

